# How to handle Fortran RTL error with JNA?

Tags: java, error-handling, fortran, jna, error-code

I'm running a shared library (compiled with Intel) using JNA. In rare cases the Fortran-call ends with a `forrtl : severe` code. Something like

```
forrtl: severe (408): fort: (3): Subscript #1 of the array IWU has value 0 which is less than the lower bound of 1
```

Is there a way to "catch" this runtime error using JNA?

Comment: I think it would be better to fix the error, Fortran starts its arrays by default with index 1 and this has probably not been considered in your code.

Comment: Are you sure the results correct when the error doesn't happen?

Comment: @albert Of course it would, but this is much mure difficult. We are running this Fortran simulation in a big-data environment (millions of different inputs, some of them may be faulty(unrealistic), a certain fault-tolerance would be nice.

Comment: Yes fault-tolerance might be necessary but this concerns the data and the handling of the data in the program, not an subscript error as this clearly indicates a programming error where a condition is not handled properly which results in an incorrect index. In the later case an error code / message should be set that is given back over JNI or a correct index should be chosen.

Answer (score 0):

There is no general mechanism for passing error codes from native code to JNA.  At best, JNA will know the function failed from its return value.

However, if the native code provides a means of reading those error codes (e.g., the Windows `GetLastError()` function, or the global `errno` variable on Linux and macOS), then more specific details can be retrieved.

For an Intel Fortran "severe" error, program execution stops unless it's handled on the native side, so I don't think there's anything you can do to "catch" it in JNA unless it's already "caught" in the library you're using... in which case, you just need to properly react to the failed method call. The Fortran source can be modified to catch some runtime errors (such as in [I/O](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/fortran-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference/top/compiler-reference/error-handling/handling-run-time-errors/list-of-run-time-error-messages.html), dynamic memory management or image control) and return this status. However, for this particular array bounds error of the question, this may not apply.

Comment: `iostat` and `errsns` apply to I/O system conditions. Array access out of bounds isn't an error generated there.

Comment: It's on the list at the link, which includes a `1` supserscript for errors not returned by IOSTAT. There's no `1` on 408.  But I don't know.  Which is why I said "may be possible".  Otherwise, the rest of the answer sums up the situation.

Comment: To quote from the table description from that link: "In the following table of example messages, the first column lists error numbers returned to IOSTAT variables when an I/O error is detected."  "IOSTAT" variables are used in I/O statements as a means of avoiding program termination (so would not have been used in any error termination I/O statement).  They are not global variables available for general runtime errors such as bounds checking errors.

Comment: Fair enough. I was trying to both answer the OP's specific question AND give more information for a more general case.  Feel free to edit my answer if you think it is currently wrong as written.

Comment: I've tried an edit in line with that. Naturally, please roll back or adapt as you see fit. I won't need to comment again.